# Thread safe Java pool, with INSTANT READ

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

To write a fully functional pool of Java objects, using READ/WRITE locks is not a big problem.
The problem I see is that READ operation will have to wait until the storage monitor (or something similar, depending on the model) is released, which really slows it.

So, the following requirements should be met:

1. READ (or GET) operation should be INSTANT - using some key, the latest version of the object should be returned immediately, without waiting for any lock.
2. WRITE (CREATE/UPDATE) - may be queued, reasonably delayed in time, probably waiting for some storage lock.

Any code sample?

---

I didn't find a question that directly targets the issue.

It popped up in some discussions, but I couldn't find a question that was fully devoted to the problems of creating such a pool in Java.

Comment: What about using [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)?

Comment: A pattern similar to CopyOnWriteArrayList might help. A write gets the write lock, copies the pool, adds the new item to the copy and finally changes the pool reference to the copy so that readers can access the new pool. You can probably remove locking completely on the reading side by making the pool volatile.

Comment: That's exactly what I though CopyOnWriteArrayList, the only thing is this - is reference reassignment a thread safe operation?

Comment: It is, when using `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 0):

when the modification on the datastructure takes too long (for whatever reason), simply waiting and write-locking the structure will not be successful. You just cannot foresee when you will have enough time to perform the modification without blocking any reads.

the only thing you can do (try to do) is to reduce the time within the write-operation to a minimum. As @assylias stated, a CopyOnWrite* does this by cloning the datastructure upon write operations and atomically activates the modified structure when the operation is complete.

By this the read-locks will take as long as the duration of the clone-operation plus the time for switching the reference. You can work that down to small parts of the datastructure: if only states in an object change, you can modify a copy of that object and change the reference in your more complex datastructure to that copy afterwards.

The other way around is to do that copy on or before read operations. Often you return a copy of an Object via the API of you datastructure anyway, so just "cache" that copy and during the modifications let the readers access the cached copy. This is what database-caches aso do.

It depends on your model what is best for you. If you will have few writes on data that can be copied easily, CopyOnWrite will probably perform best. If you will have lots of writes you probably better provide a single "read"/cached-state of your structure and switch it from time to time.

```
AtomicReference<Some> datastructure = ...; 

//copy on write

synchronized /*one writer*/ void change(Object modification) 
throws CloneNotSupportedException {
   Object copy = datastructure.clone();
   apply(copy, modification);
   datastructure.set(copy);  
}

Object search(Object select) {
   return datastructure.get().search(select);
}

// copy for read

AtomicReference<Some> cached = new AtomicReference<Some>(datastructure.get().clone());

synchronized void change(Object modification) {
    apply(datastructure, modification);
    cached.set(datastructure);
}

Object search(Object select) {
    return cached.get().search(select);
}
```

For both operations there is no wait when reading .. but for the time it needs to switch the reference.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply use a volatile variable to avoid locking on the reader side and keep the writes exclusive with a `synchronized` method. `volatile` will add little to no overhead to reads but writes will be a little slow. This might be a good solution depending on expected throughput and read/write ratio.

```
class Cache {
    private volatile Map<K, V> cache; //Assuming map is the right data structure

    public V get(K key) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    //synchronized writes for exclusive access
    public synchronized void put(K key, V value) {
        Map<K, V> copy = new HashMap<> (cache);
        V value = copy.put(key, value);
        //volatile guarantees that this will be visible from the getter
        cache = copy;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a totally-lock-free Java object pool solution. FYI

http://daviddengcn.blogspot.com/2015/02/a-lock-free-java-object-pool.html